# C# MongoDB Driver - How to filter by arrays and a list of items

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to perform a search on an array of strings and compare it to any string in a list of strings. For example:

This is the data structure:

```
{
    "CategoryIds": [ "A123", "B456", "C789" ]
}
```

and this is the search term:

```
List<string> search = new List<string> { "A123", "C789" };
```

I'm building my search query dynamically so I have these defined for start:

```
var builder = Builders<Item>.Filter;
ar filters = Builders<Item>.Filter.Empty;
```

I've tried all of the following approaches but none worked:

Using `ElemMatch`

```
filters &= builder.ElemMatch(i => i.CategoryIds, id => search.CategoryIds.Any(i => i.Equals(id)));
```

Using `Intersect`

```
filters &= builder.Where(i => search.CategoryIds.Intersect(i.CategoryIds).Any());
```

The only one that works is this one:

```
var categoryFilters = new List<FilterDefinition<Item>>();

foreach (string id in search.CategoryIds)
    categoryFilters.Add(builder.AnyEq(i => i.CategoryIds, id));

if (categoryFilters.Any())
    filters &= builder.Or(categoryFilters);
```

But it seems like overkill. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- To match a field containing *an array of values* against *a single value*, you need an [`AnyEq`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyEq__1_1.htm) filter.
- To match a *single field value* against *multiple values*, you need an [`In`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_In__1_1.htm) filter.
- To compare a field containing *an array of values* against *multiple values*, you need a combination of both, namely an [`AnyIn`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyIn__1_1.htm) filter:

```cs
var builder = Builders<Item>.Filter
filter = builder.AnyIn(item => item.CategoryIds, categoryIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the exact above use case If we want to apply **limit** or **skip** to that, Of course we can do in linq but that will **bring entire documents from the collection** that satisfy the filter condition then will apply limit or skip conditions on top of that, So for larger dataset it is suggested to apply those kind of stuffs in DB level itself.

A better way is to have an aggregate pipeline for this, If anyone looking for the one, here is below code

And a small change ,instead of list we can have a BsonArray contain search elements.

```
// Your search Array
BsonArray search = new BsonArray
                {
                    "A123", "C789"
                };

//Pipeline
var pipeline1 = new BsonDocument(
                     new BsonDocument
                        ("$match",
                            new BsonDocument
                            ( "CategoryIds",
                                new BsonDocument
                                    ("$elemMatch",
                                        new BsonDocument
                                        ("$in",
                                            search
                                        )
                                    )
                             )
                          )
                       );


BsonDocument[] pipeline = new BsonDocument[] { pipeline1 };

var results = await collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```